# How to keep static resource requests out of the filter on Spring Security WebFlux Reactive Application

Tags: spring, spring-security

I understand the following on the spring security servlet application:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().mvcMatchers(""/favicon.ico", "/doc.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/**/v2/api-docs"");
}
```

The following requests go through the filter on spring security Reactive application:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain( ServerHttpSecurity http ) {
            
    final String[] skipSwaggerUrls = new String[] {
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/doc.html",
                    "/webjars/**",
                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/**/v2/api-docs" };
            http.authorizeExchange()
                    .pathMatchers( skipSwaggerUrls ).permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
                    .and().csrf().disable()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .bearerTokenConverter( new JwtExtractTokenAuthenticationConverter() )
                    .authenticationEntryPoint( new UserAuthenticationEntryPoint() )
                    .accessDeniedHandler( new UserAccessDeniedHandler() )
                    .jwt();
    
            return http.build();
    }
```

How to keep static resource requests out of the filter on Spring Security WebFlux Reactive Application?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem at present, Just as follows

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain( ServerHttpSecurity http ) {

    final String[] skipUrls = new String[] { "/user-account/user/login" };

    final String[] skipSwaggerUrls = new String[] {
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/doc.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/**/v2/api-docs" };

    JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter( new JwtTokenGrantedAuthoritiesConverter() );
    ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(
            authenticationConverter );
    
    // change
    ServerWebExchangeMatcher pathMatchers = ServerWebExchangeMatchers
            .pathMatchers( ArrayUtils.addAll( skipUrls, skipSwaggerUrls ) );

    http.securityMatcher( new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher( pathMatchers ) )
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers( "/**" ).access( new UserAuthorityReactiveAuthorizationManager() )
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter( new AuthWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION )
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .bearerTokenConverter( new JwtExtractTokenAuthenticationConverter() )
            .authenticationEntryPoint( new UserAuthenticationEntryPoint() )
            .accessDeniedHandler( new UserAccessDeniedHandler() )
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter( jwtAuthenticationConverter );

    return http.build();
}
```

this is my [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9365)